# How to add multiple locations in google map for one company?

Tags: google-maps, seo

I have multiple addresses, I need google maps to point to all the locations of my company. How can I add these locations in google map for my company?

Comment: You will have to draw markers to show all the places. For that you either need the lat long values of your locations. You can see Google Maps examples for a better understanding.
[Exapmles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Answer (score 3):

Google allows and accepts multiple locations for single business.
Go to: https://www.google.com/local/manage/

Login to your official G-mail ID, It asks for user agreement. Accept it.

There you get a pop-up saying to import the business location in the below format and the business name.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtAMaLBhiYxedHRucWhlVUxNZ0QwOUJJSDFwbDRkd2c&&&_ga=1.41747554.1560354154.1443733879#gid=0

Import and verify the address to get listed in the Google Business Places